# How to suppress stacktrace in Ruby exit?

Tags: ruby, interrupt, ruby-2.2

```
  trap 'TERM' do
    warn 'Exiting.'
    exit 1
  end
```

This prints a 10 line stacktrace.

How to suppress the stacktrace and exit silently?

Ruby 2.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
trap "TERM" do
  warn "Exiting."
  $stderr.reopen(IO::NULL)
  $stdout.reopen(IO::NULL)
  exit 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hit <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>, the signal will be `INT`, not `TERM`. If you want to catch both, you can do something like this:

```
p = proc do
  warn 'Exiting.'
  exit 1
end
trap 'INT',p
trap 'TERM',p
```